# for loop - Not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2) but I am providing it with 3

Tags: python, python-3.8

```
def func(a,b,c):
    for x,y,z in a,b,c:
        pass

func(((1,2),(1,3)),((1,4),(1,5)),(1,2))
```

I expect `x,y,z` to get the values `(1,2)`, `(1,4)`, and `1`. Instead I'm getting an error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Comment: If you printed out x y and z inside that loop what do you expect to see?

Comment: @Alterlife (1,2),(1,4) & 1 as they would be the values of x,y & z.

Comment: Ah, in that case Ann Zen has figured out your question and answered it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a,b,c` is a tuple with the parentheses implicit. It's the same as `(a,b,c)`.

```
for x,y,z in (a,b,c):
```

This loop doesn't unpack `a` into `x`, `b` into `y`, `c` into `z`. Instead it has three iterations. The first iteration it attempts to unpack `a` into `x,y,z`. The next iteration unpacks `b`, and the third unpacks `c`.

Can `a` be unpacked into `x,y,z`? Well, `a` is a tuple with two elements: `(1,2)` and `(1,3)`. Two elements can't be unpacked into three variables. So no, it can't. And that's why you get an error message "expected 3, got 2".

I don't know what you intend this code to do. You could perhaps fix it by wrapping `(a,b,c)` in an additional iterable. Either of these:

```
for x,y,z in ((a,b,c),):
for x,y,z in [(a,b,c)]:
```

Or if you want one element from each of the three, use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over all three tuples in tandem:

```
for x,y,z in zip(a,b,c):
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) the lists in order to do a for-loop like that without iterating through the arguments passed into `func()`:

```
def func(a,b,c):
    for x,y,z in zip(a,b,c):
        pass

func(((1,2),(1,3)),((1,4),(1,5)),(1,2))
```

Otherwise, the for-loop will iterate through every argument passed into `func`.